# Clear multiple entries form "Open With" context menu

Tags: macos, shortcut-menu

How do I clear multiple entries of the same application from the "Open With" context menu?

Comment: Awesome rephrasing of this question - I'll link it to our older version of this quesion so others can see the answer no matter how they search the site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the Launch Services Database

Use the following command in the terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Wait until the terminal returns you to a prompt.  You should now be all set.

My understanding is that this will work in anything from 10.5 and up.